# Save image Uri as an image

Tags: java, android, uri

So what I am doing is receiving data as an intent from another app. I am getting the image than attempting to save it

```
  void savefile(Uri sourceuri)
{
    String sourceFilename= sourceuri.getPath();
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "PhotoSaver");


    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    try {
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFilename));
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(mediaStorageDir, false));
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        bis.read(buf);
        do {
            bos.write(buf);
        } while(bis.read(buf) != -1);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            if (bis != null) bis.close();
            if (bos != null) bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "PhotoSaver"))));

}
```

Comment: your question is not clear.What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I want to be able to save the Uri as an image in my gallery

Answer (score 1):

You should be reading till you reach the end of your input stream and finally flush your output stream. Something like this:

```
     // the file is read to the end
     while ((value = bis.read()) != -1) {
        bos.write(value);
     }

     // invokes flush to force bytes to be written out to baos
     bos.flush();
```